# How to change color of d3.js chart slices to green and red only

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to make a sunbrust chart in d3.js. Now my chart is getting the random colors. What I want is when the value is positive the slice should be green and when the value is negative the slice should be red. I am trying to attach the code but it is showing there is too much code so I am attaching the js fiddle link in the comment.

Comment: heres the link to jsfiddle file https://jsfiddle.net/8auwtvgj/

Comment: Where are negative values on your chart? All seems to be positive, that too in the thousands. Am I missing something?

Comment: These are just dummy values.

Comment: I am just trying to set the custom color of the slices as red and green.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.